# Two possible expressions for Hamiltonian of quantum critical Ising chain

Tags: homework-and-exercises, condensed-matter, ising-model, lattice-model

While reading [an article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.6282) I encountered an expression for Hamiltonian of so called "critical chain":
 $$ H = \sum_{k} c^{\dagger}_k[\sigma_x \sin k +B(1-\cos k)\sigma_y]c_k \quad (1)$$

where $c_k$ is 2-component spinor, $\sigma_i$ - Pauli matrix, $k$ is momentum, B is some constant.
 I want to see whether this is just different expression of critical Ising chain. Its Hamiltonian is known to be given by following expression:
$$H(\sigma) = -J \sum_{i=1,...N}\sigma_i^{z}\sigma_{i+1}^{z} - h\sum_{i} \sigma_i^{x} \quad(2)$$

First, I transform (1) to spacial representation by means of discrete Fourier transformations:
 $$c^{\dagger}_{k}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_{r} e^{-ikr} c^{\dagger}_{r}; \quad \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k} e^{ik(n-n')}=\delta(n-n')$$

After some effort I obtain following expression:
$$H =\sum_{r} c^{\dagger}_{[r+1]} \bigg(\frac{\sigma_x}{2i} - \frac{B}{2} \sigma_y \bigg)c_{[r]} - c^{\dagger}_{[r ]}\bigg(\frac{\sigma_x}{2i} + \frac{B}{2} \sigma_y \bigg)c_{[r+1]} +c^{\dagger}_{[r]} B \sigma_{y}c_{[r]}$$

Next step I'm trying to do is to rewrite $\sigma_i$ in terms of $c_{[i]},c^{\dagger}_{[i+1]}$. I have found in Wikipedia  [following expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ising_model):

$$\sigma_z = \sum K_1 c_{[i]}^{\dagger}c_{[i]}$$
$$\sigma_i^x = Dc_{[i]}^{\dagger}c_{[i+1]} +D^{*} c_{[i]}^{\dagger}c_{[i-1]} + K c_{[i]}c_{[i+1]}+ K^{*} c_{[i]}^{\dagger}c_{[i+1]}^{\dagger}$$
where K,D are some constants. 
However I still can't show that these two expressions for Hamiltonians are equivalent. Do they actually describe different systems? Or is there a better way to show their equivalence?

Comment: I've also tried to use [Jordan–Wigner transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%E2%80%93Wigner_transformation). It is able to rewrite $c[r]$ in terms of sigma-matrices living on given site [r]. Yet in this case I don't understand how to interpret sigma-matrices from brackets, which don't seem to live on any specific site.

Answer (score 0):

So far I have two possible solutions to this problem(which seem to contradict to each other). I've decided to write an answer rather than edit question itself because: 
1) I have found plenty of useful information about the subject. So it may also be useful to other people. 
2)If I put this information to the question it'll become too large and hence unreadable.

So here it goes.
**First strategy**

*Obtained result:* According to this approach Hamiltonian (1) is equivalent to the following one:
$$H =\sum_{r} \frac{1}{2}(\sigma^{y}_r\sigma^{x}_{r+1}+\sigma^{x}_r\sigma^{y}_{r+1}) \quad (3)$$

*Used techniques and (possibly) tricky moments:*
Firstly I've used definition of two-component spinor $c_k$, k-momentum found in the internet:
  \begin{align}  c_k=\begin{pmatrix}
           a_{k} \\                       
           a^{\dagger}_{-k} 
          \end{pmatrix} 
\quad c^{\dagger}_{k}= (a^{\dagger}_k; a_{-k})
\end{align}

where $a_k$ is fermionic annihilation operator in momentum space representation.

Once above expression used we obtain following expression:
$$H=a_{-k}a_{k}(\sin k+ Bi(1-\cos k))+a^{\dagger}_k a^{\dagger}_{-k}(\sin k- Bi(1-\cos k))$$
Then I use following discrete Fourier transformations:
$$a_r=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}e^{ikr}a_k; \quad a_k=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}e^{-ikr}a_r; \quad \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k}e^{ik(n-n')}=\delta(n-n') $$
where $k = \frac{2\pi}{N}n;\quad n= - \frac{N}{2}+1, ... \frac{N}{2}.$
 Substitution of these expressions into the Hamiltonian produces:

$$H =i \sum_r (a_{r+1} a_{r} + a^{\dagger}_{r+1} a^{\dagger}_r)$$
This expression **looks strange** to me, because it doesn't depend on B - original parameter of theory. Yet I have arrived to this expression in two different ways.

Now I use [Jordan–Wigner transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%E2%80%93Wigner_transformation). It helps me to rewrite $a_r, a^{\dagger}_r$ operators in terms of Pauli matrices. Among other properties of sigma matrices I've used the fact that they commute at different sites. This is how I arrived to (3).

**Second strategy**

This one is mainly based on following [article](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwivj6yfo-zSAhVsG5oKHVVHAJIQFgghMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.springer.com%2Fcda%2Fcontent%2Fdocument%2Fcda_downloaddocument%2F9783642330384-c2.pdf%3FSGWID%3D0-0-45-1364326-p174604005&usg=AFQjCNFdaIdGfjDNJnbLlmNAyhMZJu12rw&sig2=0z_4HzQ4wo_Wqh5qt5Y0MA&bvm=bv.150475504,d.bGs). 
They start from Hamiltonian (2) and after certain transformations(similar to ones described above) they arrive to following expression:

$$H=N-2\sum_{q}(1+\lambda \cos q)a^{\dagger}_q a_q - \lambda \sum_q (e^{-iq} a^{\dagger}_q a^{\dagger}_{-q } -e^{iq} a_{q}a_{-q})$$ 
where $\lambda$ is a constant defined by Ising model.

Now if I take B=1 in (1) I may arrive to following expression:
$$H=\sum_{k} -ic_{-k}c_{k} e^{ik} + i  c^{\dagger}_{k} c^{\dagger}_{-k} e^{-ik}$$
This expression resembles the previous one. This may hint to the fact that Hamiltonians (1) and (2) are the same one after all. Yet I can't reconcile this hyphotesis with expression (3). 
If one can see some mistakes in my reasoning or has useful links, please let me know.

Comment: If $c_k$ is a two component spinor wouldn't $c_k=\begin{pmatrix}
           c_{k\alpha} \\                       
           a^{\dagger}_{k\beta} 
          \end{pmatrix} $ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are some indices such as spin up/down? Why did you set it to two operators with opposite $k$ signs? I am not too familiar with this subject so maybe incorrect.

Comment: Let me show explicitly how this expression came to life. We start from so called Nambu-spinor representation: \begin{align}  c_r=\begin{pmatrix} a_{r} \\      a^{\dagger}_{r}   \end{pmatrix}  \end{align} where r denotes number of site. Now we use aforementioned Fourier transforms for $a_r, a^{\dagger}_r$. In particular $a^{\dagger}_r = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} e^{ikr} a^{\dagger}_{-k}$. Then we can see that  \begin{align}  c_r= \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} e^{ikr} \begin{pmatrix} a_{k} \\      a^{\dagger}_{-k} \end{pmatrix}  \end{align}  where column now is nothing more than $\psi_k$

Comment: I guess in my notation $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are implied yet not written explicitly.